# Making a single file of a private repo on Gitlab to be publicly accessible

Tags: gitlab, wget

I have a bash script file in my GitLab private repo. I wish to download the file in Linux when running the `wget` command, however it fails to do so since the file is hosted in a private repo, thus it goes to Login page.

Is there a way to make this single file publicly accessible? If not, is there a way to include my credentials in the GET URL when attempting to open the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use `curl`, you can use the GitLab API to [get a raw file from repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository). You'd need to add your private-token as well to get this file.

For example:

`curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/repository/files/FILE_NAME/raw?ref=BRANCH' --output FILE_NAME`

Comment: You don't need to use curl for this. Wget can do the job equally well

Comment: From where do I need to generate the "PRIVATE-TOKEN" ?

Comment: @Benjamin Top right of gitlab, `Settings` -> `Access Tokens`, and then `Add a personal access token` with the access you require.

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned by @darnir, I could have achieve the same thing using 'wget' command.

Comment: As this is probably what the OP needed, it doesn't answer the question as it is stated now.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Revkoni, you can use the [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository) for this:

`$ wget --header="PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXXX" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/PROJECT_ID/repository/files/FILE_NAME/raw?ref=BRANCH"`

Comment: From where do I need to generate the "PRIVATE-TOKEN" ?